# Why got 404 while add project name in entry point url

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

If run project with *Spring* security, the entry point URL is:

> http://localhost:8099/login

Meanwhile I need to put global project name in entry point URL as follows:

> http://localhost:8099/pojoname/login

Here down is my Spring Security Configuration file:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/register", "/registration", "/editProfile").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("email")
        .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: You could change the application's context path: `server.servlet.context-path=/pojoname`.

Comment: Did you tried putting your project inside a new pojoname folder?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS if i put my pojo inside different folder path is never change because of path is produced by spring security

Comment: But if you do not have a pojoname folder then how are you going to call `http://localhost:8099/pojoname/login`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested feature is what is know as web context (or formerly *Servlet* context in a *Servlet* container work).

This is supported out of the box within *Spring Boot* and can be switched / activated using the configuration property `server.servlet.contextPath` with the desired value.

Inside your `application.properties` file, add below line:

- For a version < *Spring Boot 2.0*:

  ```
    server.contextPath=/pojoname
  ```
- For a version > *Spring Boot 2.0*:

  ```
    server.servlet.contextPath=/pojoname
  ```

Comment: Great to be in help, don't forget to accept the answer if it works :)